# Who is considered as infidel (kafir) from the viewpoint of noble Qur'an?

Tags: tafseer, islamic-philosophy, kuffar, surat-at-tawbah

The word Kafir (infidel) is used many times in noble Qur'an. [[Ref]](http://searchtruth.com/search.php?keyword=Kafir&chapter=&translator=6&search=1&start=0&records_display=10&search_word=all)

such as:

> يُرِيدُونَ أَن يُطْفِئُوا نُورَ اللَّـهِ بِأَفْوَاهِهِمْ وَيَأْبَى
>   اللَّـهُ إِلَّا أَن يُتِمَّ نُورَهُ وَلَوْ كَرِهَ الْكَافِرُونَ
>
> *Sahih international translation*:
>   They want to extinguish the light of Allah with their mouths, but
>   Allah refuses except to perfect His light, although the disbelievers
>   dislike it. [[9:32]](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/9:32)

Can a comprehensive definition of "infidel" be derived using Qur'anic verses? In other words, Who is infidel (kafir) in the Qur'an point of view?

Comment: If you revise these verses you could have an image about the Qur'an point of view about Al-Kafir ... and Allah knows better ... cheers ...

Comment: The word "Kaafir" is used over a 100 times in the Quran.

Comment: @Sayyid Yeah, you are right. Thanks for your precious comment! I'll edit my post right now.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of infidel is a person who does not believe in religion or who adheres to a religion other than one's own.

The definition of Kaafir is  person who is not a Muslim.

Someone is considered Kaafir if they do not believe in Islam. If they deny that there is One God and He is Allah and Mohammed is His Messenger.

Christians who believe that Isa (as) is God are kuffar:

> Surely, disbelievers are those who say, “Allah is the Masīh, son of
>   Maryam” while the Masīh had said, “O children of Isrā’īl , worship
>   Allah, my Lord and your Lord.” In fact, whoever ascribes any partner
>   to Allah, Allah has prohibited for him the Jannah (the Paradise), and
>   his shelter is the Fire, and there will be no supporters for the
>   unjust. [(al-Ma'idah: 72)](http://tanzil.net/#5:72)

Christians who believe in a trinity are kuffar:

> Surely, disbelievers are those who say, “Allah is the third of the
>   three” while there is no god but One God. If they do not desist from
>   what they say, a painful punishment shall certainly befall such
>   disbelievers.
>
> [(al-Ma'idah: 73)](http://tanzil.net/#5:73)

Comment: Thanks! there are some points: 1-use Quranic verses as the question wants. 2-Do you mean that infidel is different from kafir?

Comment: Infidel can be used by any religion however Kaafir is a word used only in Islam by Muslims to describe non-Muslims. They both mean the same thing.

Comment: So, a christian is infidel from Quran viewpoint? according to which verse?

Comment: @MohammadHossein check my answer

Comment: Now it's too much better, while might be improved by presenting a more general answer and not only focusing and such christians.

Comment: I gave you a general answer then you asked about Christians and that is what I answered for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15457/discussion-between-mohammad-hossein-and-zohal).

Answer (score 2):

Kafir is literally someone who buries a seed, and covers it.

In Qur'an, word Kafir is specially used for group of people among non-muslims, who have been rejected Islam after understanding it (and also group of people who took arms against Islam). Consider following ayah;

> إِنَّ الَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا سَوَاءٌ عَلَيْهِمْ أَأَنذَرْتَهُمْ أَمْ لَمْ
>   تُنذِرْهُمْ لَا يُؤْمِنُونَ

Losely translated, this ayah says that it is same for "the ones who disbelieved" whether you warn them or not, they are not to believe. Notice that the word كَفَرُوا (they disbelieved) is in the past tense here. Hinting at the fact that they have already disbelieved and their disbelief is certain.

Moreover, see the following ayah;

> مَّا يَوَدُّ الَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا مِنْ أَهْلِ الْكِتَابِ وَلَا
>   الْمُشْرِكِينَ أَن يُنَزَّلَ عَلَيْكُم مِّنْ خَيْرٍ مِّن رَّبِّكُمْ ۗ
>   وَاللَّهُ يَخْتَصُّ بِرَحْمَتِهِ مَن يَشَاءُ ۚ وَاللَّهُ ذُو الْفَضْلِ
>   الْعَظِيمِ

In this ayah, Allah (c.c) talks about Kafirs **among** "people of the book" and polytheists. If all non-muslims were Kafirs, saying Kafirs **from** "people of the book" and Polytheist would make less sense. In this ayah, Allah (c.c) makes a difference between Kafirs and 2 groups of non-muslims.

So, kafirs are those people who have been made dawah for some time, they come to understand islam but decided to reject it anyways and are certain on their rejection.

Answer (score 0):

Islam commands this in 4:48 Surah An-Nisa
Indeed, Allah does not forgive associating others with Him in worship,1 but forgives anything else of whoever He wills. And whoever associates others with Allah has indeed committed a grave sin.

Only Allah speaks for Allah, anyone who speaks for him appart from the prophet has commited a great sin, so all Imam who create laws outside of sharia in the name of Allah are not only sinners but grave sinners.

Allah speaks to the hearth of men trough dreams and trought the Quran anything else is man's work.

When Allah created the Quran he was writing it to guide Mohammed and his followers, he never wished for it to be made a organized religion, however Mohammed's family murderers claimed to speak in the name of Allah and created religion and waged war against all even the christians and the Jews this is the Suni and Shia divide the Suni believe it that his son-in-law was to guide the followers and the Shia believed his most Loyal Follower Ali was to guide the people.

To be honest the Quran prohibits murder of muslims, so both were very wrong in fighting between themselves.

They should have followed the Quran and shared in the power under the peace of Allah and the words of the prophet but were tempted to fight by the devil and both claimed to speak for Allah to gain legitimacy commiting a two grave sins for power.

So it depends who you follow:
For Shia Muslim other religions and Suni are Unbelievers
For Suni Muslim other religions and Shia are Unbelievers
On the Quran all who dared speak in the name of Allah are Unbelievers and not to be trusted.

The Quran was writen to guide the Believers, yet after Muhammed all turned against each other turning into unbelievers creating temples instead of praying from their homes to Mecah.

So the true Muslim should hear Allah and Allah only and never claim to speak in his name, or acept others who claim the same to do so is Haram.

He should also read the whole of the Quran and not only the parts he finds to be beneficial to him, so that he won't contradict himself.

So in truth Unbelievers are those who deny the voice of Allah and the Quran is but a guide to help you hear it for yourself trough the experiences of the prophet.

Men will do what they do they will fight and Allah sees no Sin in fighting but he sees sin in killing, specially when it is the killing of those who offer peace.

4:94
O believers! When you struggle in the cause of Allah, be sure of who you fight. And do not say to those who offer you ˹greetings of˺ peace, “You are no believer!”—seeking a fleeting worldly gain.1 Instead, Allah has infinite bounties ˹in store˺. You were initially like them then Allah blessed you ˹with Islam˺. So be sure! Indeed, Allah is All-Aware of what you do.

Again Alah will choose those who will receive his words out of the deserving, but is not up for us to choose who believes in it or not only Allah can convince people.

And peraphs Allah has a different path set for them, so we shouldn't question it not knowing were it leads for he is all knowing and merciful.

So an unbeliever just those who refuse the word of Allah, and instead choose to follow the word of Men and be enslaved by it. For many a sin comes from following false prophets. Yet no sin was ever made by a man who trully acepted Allah in his love and mercy as his sheperd and trusted Allah would guide the others on the same path, after all a single sheep can go astray but it will come back in fear but a herd is only lost when sheep start to follow other sheep, so what does Allah say to you with the soul he gave you does it lead to the stony path on the hill or to the grassfields close to the river? Its all a part of his path none are trully lost unless they choose to do so.